# Setting Up a Rails Application on a Subdirectory of Joomla site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, joomla2.5, apache2.2

I have a joomla site in my domain root, i.e www.myjoomlasite.com and I have a rails application in www.myrailssite.com/railsapp

I want to deploy the rails application in a sub-directory of http://www.myjoomlasite.com, expecting that rails application will be available in  http://www.myjoomlasite.com/railsapp.

After doing all necessary steps when i click, *www.myjoomlasite.com/railsapp* in browser, it redirect me correctly to http://www.myjoomlasite.com/railsapp/admins/sign_in

Then in spite of displaying the **sign_in** page, it displayed joomla's error page  "404 page not found"

My questions are:

1. If anything wrong with the rails application it should display rails
   error page, but why joomla's error page?
2. In rails application production log why it showing  **Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms** ?
3. How can i deploy rails application in a sub-directory of my joomla site?

**Additional information:**

rails application production log

```
Started GET "/railsapp" for 24.5.7.81 at 2012-09-14 08:41:36 -0700
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the possible reason behind '404'. I have .htaccess file in document root. This .htaccess file stoping rails application to render.

Is it possible make some changes in .htaccess file show that, rails app can render properly?

Comment: If i add a Rewrite Condition in .htaccess file will it create any issue? I add following line in htaccess `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/railsapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a .htaccess file in document root. This default .htaccess file comes with joomla source code ( as htaccess.txt, letter is was renamed to .htaccess). There is one  **RewriteRule** based upon some **RewriteCond** . All the rewrite condition, that are comes with default htaccess file, stopping my "/railsapp" url to render. To allow to pass my "/railsapp" i add following **RewriteCond** in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/railsapp
```

If any url start with 'railsapp' prefix, then those url will not rewrited by rewrite rule and visit that url directly.